# Rails: submit child model in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I've researched a while on this topic but haven't found a real solution to what I am trying to achieve.

I'm working with a nested one-to-many nested form (Project has many Tasks). And each task has many attributes, e.g. type, assigned_individual, due_date, etc. I got no problem having the parent Project and the nested child model Tasks saved/updated on one submit. But what I need to achieve seems to be the opposite of this effort. I need one Ajax save call for each Task besides the global submit. so when the task list gets long, users don't have to worry about losing what they have written earlier for the other tasks. They can click that save button and get's a feedback saying that what he has entered for the task has been saved.

Currently the Project is in a form_for wrapper, and the Tasks are in fields_for partial
these are the simplified version of what I have right now.
Here is the form in edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
   <p>f.text_field :title</p>
   <p>f.text_field :author</p>
   <%= render :partial=> 'tasks', :collection=> @project.tasks %>
<%= f.submit 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Here is tasks partial:

```
<%= fields_for :tasks do |f| %>
  <label>Category</label>
  <%= f.text_field :category%>     
  <label>Description</label>
  <%= f.text_field :description%>  
  <label>Author</label>
  <%= f.text_field :author%> 
  <label>Assigned Individual</label>
  <%= f.text_field :assigned_individual%>
  <label>Notes</label>
  <%= f.text_area :notes%>
  <label>Due Date</label>
  <%= f.text_field :due_date%>
  <button onclick='update_task();'>Save Task</button> 
<% end %>
```

Since I cannot have multiple submit button in one form, what I can think of right now is to use jQuery to collect every single user entry in that partial and pass them as a big hash back to the Task controller update method.

```
update_task()
```

but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: finding a solution would be simpler if you paste your model and view files here

Comment: Hey Puneet, I've added some code.